# Mixed-content request from HTTPS page to HTTP (non-HTTPS) localhost address not blocked

Tags: javascript, browser, xmlhttprequest, mixed-content, secure-context

Suppose the page below is loaded from `https://127.0.100.1`. The page makes an `XMLHttpRequest`  to `http://127.0.100.2`. This seems like *[mixed content](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content)*: The page is loaded over a secure connection and a resource is loaded over an insecure connection. Mixed content should be blocked by the browser. Yet, the page below works just fine.* Why does it work: Why isn't the request blocked?

*Update: Going beyond the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60487457/3664487), browsers [can be configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60456809/blocking-mixed-content-from-potentially-trustworthy-origins-127-0-0-0-8/) to block mixed content for such addresses.*

<sup>* Wireshark confirms browsers aren't loading the resource over a secure connection.</sup>

```
<html>
<body>
<img id="dst"/>
<script>
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('get', 'http://127.0.100.2/img.jpg');
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('dst').src = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);    
  }
  xhr.send();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @sideshowbarker Your answer seems right. _a priori authenticated URL_ meaning _We know a priori that a request to a particular URL...will be delivered in a way that mitigates the risks of interception and modifications_ which includes URLs from _a potentially trustworthy URL_, where _A potentially trustworthy URL_ includes _one whose origin is a potentially trustworthy origin_ and _A potentially trustworthy origin is one which a user agent can generally trust as delivering data securely_, including when a _origin’s host component matches one of the CIDR notations 127.0.0.0/8 or ::1/128_

Comment: This behaviour makes testing rather problematic! @sideshowbarker Is there a reasonable way to test for such behaviour when running websites on localhost?

Comment: Can be more specific about what you mean by *“way to test for such behaviour"*? I’m guessing you don’t mean, a way to test that a host is in the 127.0.0.0 - 127.255.255.255 range (because that seems easily testable). So maybe you mean, is there a way to test whether the URL is considered a secure context or not? If so, no, the specifications and the platform don’t define any API for browsers to expose for doing any kind of testing for that? Or if that’s not what you mean, then please clarify further.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I should have been clearer: How can I change my testing environment to see mixed content being blocked?

Comment: I think you can’t change your testing environment to see mixed content being blocked — at least not in the way I assume you mean. It’s not observable from frontend JavaScript code. Basically all you can do is something like what the test at https://wpt.live/mixed-content/imageset.https.sub.html does. Otherwise, from outside the browser, you might be able to do more using Selenium/WebDriver.

Comment: @sideshowbarker _something like what the test at wpt.live/mixed-content/imageset.https.sub.html does_ would be perfect. But, how can I do that using 127.0.100.1 and 127.0.100.2, given that mixed content blocking doesn't work for those?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`http://127.0.100.2/img.jpg` isn’t considered mixed content because the Mixed Content spec defines it as a special case of an [*a priori authenticated URL*](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-mixed-content/#a-priori-authenticated-url), due to it being in the range 127.0.0.0 - 127.255.255.255 (that is, a host with the CIDR notation 127.0.0.0/8), which [per the Secure Contexts spec](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-secure-contexts/#is-origin-trustworthy) is defined as a secure context — even if the protocol isn’t https.

The same goes for `http://localhost/img.jpg` or `http://foo.localhost/img.jpg`